# Unable to Stop BaseAdapter audioplayer from an activity

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, audio-player

This is my code to stop the audio player from activity while using **audio player.stop()** function without using **if condition** it causes **Null pointer Exception** Error.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(audioPlayer != null)
        audioPlayer.stop();

    if (mSimpleExoPlayer != null) 
        mSimpleExoPlayer.stop();

            audioWriteAdapters.audioPlayPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

here is the code for **audioplayer** adapter page, I want to **Stop** the audio player from activity. Initially assign the **audioplayer** as null, inside the functionality setting audio player value from the array list.audio player is working fine in the adapter view.

```
public class AudioWriteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public MediaPlayer audioPlayPlayer = null;
public boolean isPlaying = false;
String finalTimerString = "";
String secondsString = "";
private ArrayList<MessageAudio> messageAudioArrayList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private ItemClickListener clickListener;
private Runnable mRunnable;
private Handler mHandler;

public AudioWriteAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public AudioWriteAdapter(ArrayList<MessageAudio> messageAudioArrayList, Context mContext, ItemClickListener clickListener) {
    this.messageAudioArrayList = messageAudioArrayList;
    this.context = mContext;
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return messageAudioArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return messageAudioArrayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

public void clearMediaPlayer() {
    if (audioPlayPlayer != null) {
        audioPlayPlayer.release();
        audioPlayPlayer = null;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, final View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View rowView = view;
    if (rowView == null) {
        rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.audio_view_pagers, null);
        final TextView typeTitle, typeDate;
        final ImageView typeDelete, typeEdit, viewRecord, pauseViewAudio, playViewAudio;
        final LinearLayout viewAudioLayout;
        final TextThumbSeekBar audioViewSeekbar;
        typeTitle = rowView.findViewById(R.id.typeTitle);
        typeDelete = rowView.findViewById(R.id.typeDelete);
        typeEdit = rowView.findViewById(R.id.typeEdit);
        viewRecord = rowView.findViewById(R.id.viewRecord);
        viewAudioLayout = rowView.findViewById(R.id.viewAudioLayout);
        pauseViewAudio = rowView.findViewById(R.id.pauseViewAudio);
        playViewAudio = rowView.findViewById(R.id.playViewAudio);
        audioViewSeekbar = rowView.findViewById(R.id.audioViewSeekbar);
        //typeDate = typeLayout.findViewById(R.id.typeDate);
        typeTitle.setText(messageAudioArrayList.get(i).getTitle());
        //rowView.setTag("1");
        viewRecord.setTag(messageAudioArrayList.get(i).getPath());
        viewRecord.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mHandler = new Handler();

                        viewAudioLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        if (audioPlayPlayer == null) {
                            audioPlayPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                            try {

                                audioPlayPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(viewRecord.getTag()));

                                audioPlayPlayer.prepare();
                            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            audioPlayPlayer.start();
                            if (pauseViewAudio.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                pauseViewAudio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            playViewAudio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            isPlaying = true;


                            final int duration = audioPlayPlayer.getDuration();
                            audioViewSeekbar.setProgress(0);
                            audioViewSeekbar.setMax(duration / 1000);
                            mRunnable = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (audioPlayPlayer != null) {
                                        int mCurrentPosition = audioPlayPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000; // In milliseconds
                                        audioViewSeekbar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                                        String Total = ((duration / 1000) / 60) + ":" + (duration / 1000) % 60;

                                        int totalLength = duration / 1000;
                                        int remainingLength = (duration - audioPlayPlayer.getCurrentPosition()) - duration;
                                        Log.e("Duration == >", "Total length ==>" + totalLength + " Remaining ==>" + remainingLength);
                                        String remainingSeconds = String.valueOf(((remainingLength / 1000) % 60) - ((duration / 1000) / 60));
                                        if (remainingSeconds.length() < 2) {
                                            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
                                        }
                                        String remainingTotal = ((remainingLength / 1000) / 60) + ":" + remainingSeconds;
                                        Log.e("Remaining Duration == >", " Remaining ==>" + remainingTotal);
                                        //seekBar.setProgressText(remainingTotal+"/"+Total);
                                        Log.e("Cuurent Position is==>", String.valueOf(mCurrentPosition));


                                        audioViewSeekbar.setProgressText(milliSecondsToTimer(audioPlayPlayer.getCurrentPosition()) + "/" + Total);


                                    }
                                    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
                                }
                            };
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
                        }

                    }
                }
        );

        audioViewSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                        //audioPlayPlayer.seekTo(i*1000);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }
                }
        );
        pauseViewAudio.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        audioPlayPlayer.pause();
                        if (mHandler != null) {
                            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
                        }
                        isPlaying = false;
                        playViewAudio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        pauseViewAudio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
        );

        playViewAudio.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (!isPlaying) {
                            if (audioPlayPlayer != null) {

                                audioPlayPlayer.start();
                                isPlaying = true;

                                pauseViewAudio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                playViewAudio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                final int duration = audioPlayPlayer.getDuration();
                                mRunnable = new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (audioPlayPlayer != null) {
                                            int mCurrentPosition = audioPlayPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000; // In milliseconds
                                            audioViewSeekbar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                                            String Total = ((duration / 1000) / 60) + ":" + (duration / 1000) % 60;

                                            int totalLength = duration / 1000;
                                            int remainingLength = (duration - audioPlayPlayer.getCurrentPosition()) - duration;
                                            Log.e("Duration == >", "Total length ==>" + totalLength + " Remaining ==>" + remainingLength);
                                            String remainingSeconds = String.valueOf(((remainingLength / 1000) % 60) - ((duration / 1000) / 60));
                                            if (remainingSeconds.length() < 2) {
                                                remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
                                            }
                                            String remainingTotal = ((remainingLength / 1000) / 60) + ":" + remainingSeconds;
                                            Log.e("Remaining Duration == >", " Remaining ==>" + remainingTotal);
                                            //seekBar.setProgressText(remainingTotal+"/"+Total);
                                            Log.e("Cuurent Position is==>", String.valueOf(mCurrentPosition));


                                            audioViewSeekbar.setProgressText(milliSecondsToTimer(audioPlayPlayer.getCurrentPosition()) + "/" + Total);


                                        }
                                        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
                                    }
                                };
                                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        typeDelete.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (clickListener != null) {
                            //int pos = businessPartnerModelArrayList.indexOf(businessPartnerModelArrayFilteredList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                            clickListener.onWriteDeleteClick("audio", i);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    return rowView;
}
private String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds) {
    // Convert total duration into time
    int hours = (int) (milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int minutes = (int) (milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
    int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
    // Add hours if there
    if (hours > 0) {
        finalTimerString = hours + ":";
    }

    // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
    if (seconds < 10) {
        secondsString = "0" + seconds;
    } else {
        secondsString = "" + seconds;
    }
    finalTimerString = minutes + ":" + secondsString;

    // return timer string
    return finalTimerString;
}
protected void initializeAudioSeekBar() {

}
```

}

Comment: `Null pointer Exception` means that something you are trying to use is null. Therefore you have to check how you initialize it, and use debugger to find out what exactly is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: got it, But this is not a solution to solve the above-mentioned problem. My problem is unable to stop the adapter audio player from activity, can you pls help me to solve this problem. I'm struggling with this problem.

Comment: so far it is the only solution because you did not provide the details.

Comment: I posted my code above

Comment: what exactly is null in your code? How you initialize it? Those details are missing.

Comment: I have added an audio player in one of the adapter to play audios and it is working properly. But when the audio is playing and the user presses the back button, the audio still continues to play in the background. I want it to be stopped. I tried capturing the back button and tried pausing the audio but it is not working.

Comment: show the code of how you use `audioPlayer`, especially how you initialize it. Also what is null in your code? What throws exception?

Comment: posted audioplayer code above, Kindly check it.

Comment: ok, `audioplayer`  looks fine. What about `mSimpleExoPlayer`?

Comment: That is a Video player, but the problem is not able to stop the adapter audio player from activity.

Comment: in `onBackPressed` you are using 2 different `audioPlayer`. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Could you please finally say on which line do you get the NullPointerException so I can stop guessing at least which variable is a problem?

Comment: audioWriteAdapters.audioPlayPlayer.stop();

Comment: `audioWriteAdapters.audioPlayPlayer.` will be initialized only after you click on some view in your ListView. Also which one is null: `audioWriteAdapters` or `audioWriteAdapters.audioPlayPlayer`. Show the exception stacktrace

Comment: Ok, Thankyou for your prompt reply